# USB-C to Mini Display Port not detected on 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, display, dell

I have a Dell XPS13, and am trying to use an Apple monitor with Mini DisplayPort. My Dell has only a USB-c port, and I'm trying to use [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017TZTMBG). And it doesn't work-- the monitor doesn't turn on and my system doesn't detect it. `lsusb` gives

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am asking this question here because I am convinced that it is some kind of driver issue. My friend also has an XPS 13, and the adapter works fine for him. Another friend has a Thinkpad, also works fine. And it isn't my port; I can use a USB-c to VGA converter no problem. In that case, `lsusb` gives

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1fc9:5002 NXP Semiconductors 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
```

How can I begin to troubleshoot this?

---

**Edit:** Bump -_- No progress yet after going through a plethora of other SE posts

I should mention that I have Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2):

```
*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
```

**Edit 2:**

Bump. Tried playing with BIOS settings as per [this page](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2393560.html), no luck.

**Edit 3:**

Installed DisplayLink from [here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu), rebooted, no change. Followed each of the workarounds for Intel HD Graphics as given [here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades), no change. Sense of despair sets in.

Comment: did it worked somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install DisplayLink, you can use the official documentation from this link. Get the latest version from Official website

https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

And then:

- Install unzip: `sudo apt install unzip`
- Extract the downloaded file (or right click, extract): `unzip ~/Download/Display...`
- Enable execution bit on bin file: `chmod +x ./displaylink-driver-xxxxx.run`
- Finally run the installer: `sudo ./displaylink-driver-xxxxx.run`
- Remove installer and LICENSE file: rm displaylink-driver-4.4.24.run LISENSE

Official install guide:

https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu

Comment: I was very hopeful in trying this, but there's been no change-- display is not detected. I installed, rebooted, then tried a troubleshooting step on the DisplayLink website regarding Intil graphics, rebooted again, nothing. Comparing with my friends setup, we have the exact same output for `lshw -c video`, which gives our display drivers as `i915_bpo`

Comment: if you try the command `sudo journalctl -f` and unplug/plug back the adapter, did you see any useful log?